# Transform object to ArrayBuffer to send over webRTC

Tags: javascript, serialization, webrtc

I am using WebRTC to transfer files on a local network.

Since WebRTC is limited to sending between 16kb to 64kb per packet, I must split my file into chunks of a maximum size of 64kb.

Additionally, as I want to send multiple files simultaneously or in a sequenced queue, I need to include the file ID for every chunk I send. This ensures that the receiving side knows which file the chunk belongs to.

The flow of the process is as follows:

1. Device A wants to send a file and selects a file.
2. Device A sends a metadata packet to the receiver: `{ fileId: someId, fileName: 'someName', size: size }`.
3. Device A sends the first chunk: `{ fileId: someId, chunkData: ArrayBuffer }`.
   JSON.stringify` the chunk object and send it over the WebRTC connection, upon receiving and parsing it, the chunkData appears empty.

I have tried various methods to serialize and deserialize it, but I always end up encountering the same situation.

To overcome this issue, I have used an approach called the Finite-state machine, which is commonly employed in byte streaming. In this approach, upon receiving the metadata, the receiver side changes its state to read the chunks and saves the current fileId being transferred. When the transfer is complete, the state is disposed of.

However, this approach is not ideal because it doesn't allow me to transfer multiple files simultaneously, and it can be quite confusing for developers.

Is there a way to serialize complete objects, including the file data, without losing it during the transfer?

Comment: When transferring multiple files simultaneously you might use different datachannels instead. Metadata might go into the channels `protocol` field but is typically not necessary when you close the channel once all chunks have been sent.

Comment: @PhilippHancke And can I create new data channels after I established connection? I thought you must create it before the Offer. Anyway I use simple-peer and you can't do it there I thought because of the exact reason I just mentioned. I'll read about it more

Comment: I don't understand why the API so complex

Comment: In the standard API you can. simple-peer seems to abstract this away and restrict you to a single data channel.